# Why is there no interface in my current App?

Tags: android

at the moment I'm trying to program some Apps with Android Studio. I want to create an App, which shows me the values of the accelerometer. So I watched some Youtube Videos and get the right values. But now I want to display them on my mobile screen. I created an interface, but the App on my mobile doesn't show it. In addition, there is an Error Message when I try to use my Interface in the MainActivity.

If I comment out all of my Code of the accelerometer, there isn't any error and the Layout is shown right.

```
package com.example.bwki_test_accelometer;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private android.hardware.SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Initialzing Sensor Services");
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if (accelerometer== null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Der Sensor ist nicht verfügbar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL );
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Regoster accelerometer listener");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged:X:" + event.values[0] + "    Y: " +   event.values[1] + "   Z:   " + event.values[2]);

        /*
        EditText XAchse=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.XAchse);
        XAchse.setText((int) event.values[0]);

        EditText YAchse=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.YAchse);
        YAchse.setText((int) event.values[1]);

        EditText ZAchse=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ZAchse);
        ZAchse.setText((int) event.values[2]);

        */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code: setting the text to a cast integer and sleeping on the thread. First, remove the entire `try...catch` block with `Thread.sleep()`, as it's causing problems and you don't really need to pause for 1 second there. And second, do not cast your accelerometer values to int, but simply display their original float values (`setText()` expects a resource ID as integer). That commented out block could look like this (you will need to replace your EditText to TextView in a corresponding layout file):

```
TextView XAchse= findViewById(R.id.XAchse);
XAchse.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));

TextView YAchse= findViewById(R.id.YAchse);
YAchse.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));

TextView ZAchse= findViewById(R.id.ZAchse);
ZAchse.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));
```

I tested it in a quick sample app and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the Thread.sleep(...) from onSensorChanged(...)? I imagine that onSensorChanged(...) is called relatively often and this might prevent anything else happening to your application.

Android is not super excited about long running tasks on its' threads. You should run that in your own worker threads.